# Arduino analogWrite() causes program to freeze

Tags: arduino

I am writing some Arduino code that is meant to control my 3D printed robot at a basic level. Everything works fine until the value that I analogWrite() to ledPin (pin 11 on the Nano) is no longer 0. The purpose of this bit of code is to fade some leds ON/OFF based on ambient lighting without using delay() function that pauses the program.

**The code here determines whether the ambient light is below threshold, wheter 4 milliseconds have passed and whether the LEDs are at their target brightness yet, then increments/decrements the value to analogWrite() accordingly**. It's when this value (lightVal) increases that the whole program freezes and remains in the state it was just before freezing. (The robot becomes unresponsive and serial data stops getting sent.) The moment I **comment out** the analogWrite(), the freeze **does not occur**.

```
timer = millis();
aLightVal = analogRead(LDR);
aLightVal = map(aLightVal, 0, 600, 0, 100);

//Check to see if the ambient light is below threshold
//If LED is not yet at target brightness, fade every 4 milliseconds
if (aLightVal < 40){
 if (timer - currentTime > 4){
  if (lightVal < 255){

   lightVal++;
   currentTime = timer; 
  }
 }
}

if (aLightVal >= 40){
 if (timer - currentTime > 4){
  if (lightVal > 0){

  lightVal--;
  currentTime = timer;
  }
 }
}
analogWrite(ledPin, lightVal);
Serial.println(aLightVal);
```

I am using the Servo.h as well as the Ultrasonic.h libraries in the program if that helps?

I initialised the variables as follows:

```
const int LDR = A1;
const int ledPin = 11;

unsigned long timer = 0;
unsigned long currentTime = 0;
int aLightVal;
int lightVal = 0;
```

Any advice? Please let me know, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Usually, Arduino code is separated into two parts: `void setup() { }` and `void loop() { }`. How does your code fit into that scheme?

Comment: This code is within the void loop() {  } section.